# How to match all words form a document in the search query?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose there are 3 documents :

```
{
  "id": 1
  "recipe": "egg apple peach"
}
{
  "id": 2
  "recipe": "egg apple"
}
{
  "id": 3
  "recipe": "egg apple potato"
}
```

I want to lookup such that if all the words of the `recipe` field of the document are present in my search query.

So the `query : "egg apple peach"` should return the documents 1 and 2.

The `query : "egg apple"` should return the documents 2.

How can I provide this kind of query with Elasticsearch ?

Comment: The first condition contradicts the sentence above -- you wanna match *all* the words, so why would 2 match? Vice versa, why would not 1 & 2 match, but not 3?

Comment: what is your use case for such type of search, just looked at your sample and it's really rare to hv such requirements, would be interested to know use-case.

Comment: I would like to find all the recipes (documents) I can do with a list of ingredients (query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[terms_set](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html)**

> Returns documents that contain a minimum number of exact terms in a
>   provided field

This can be used to return documents when query contains minimum number of token present in document. First you need to index document with [token_count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/token-count.html) data type.

> A field of type token_count is really an integer field which accepts
>   string values, analyzes them, then indexes the number of tokens in the
>   string.

In index we will store number of token for recipe.

**Example :**
For "recipe": "egg apple potato"  recipe.length=3 
For "recipe": "egg apple"  recipe.length=2

**Mapping:**

```
PUT index12
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id":{
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "recipe":{
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "length":{
            "type":"token_count",
            "analyzer":"standard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms_set": {
      "recipe": {
        "terms": [
          "egg",
          "apple",
          "peach"
        ],
        "minimum_should_match_script": {
          "source": """ if(doc['recipe.length'].size()==0) return 0; else return doc['recipe.length'].value"""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index12",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Wj563XEBly0sCU1FGf2v",
        "_score" : 1.1871837,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "recipe" : "egg apple peach"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index12",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Wz563XEBly0sCU1FIf06",
        "_score" : 0.29748765,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 2,
          "recipe" : "egg apple"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: It won't work with the `query "egg apple peach"` because it should return the documents 1 (egg apple peach) and 2 (egg apple) The goal of my query is to find all the recipes (documents) I can do with a list of ingredients (query).
If I add a new recipe with only "egg", this document should be return also with this query.

Comment: @Hehop After creating a new index with token_count type as given in answer,  run the query. It will return those documents

Comment: @Hehop I have updated my answer with your query and its result

Comment: I got this error with your example : `"reason" : {
          "type" : "script_exception",
          "script_stack" : [
            "...Longs.get(ScriptDocValues.java:121)",
            "...Longs.getValue(ScriptDocValues.java:115)",
            "doc['recipe.length'].value",
          ],
          "script" : "doc['recipe.length'].value",
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "illegal_state_exception",
            "reason" : "A document doesn't have a value for a field! Use doc[<field>].size()==0 to check if a document is missing a field!"
          }
        }`

Comment: @Hehop ,  Error is that recipe.length was not found. Did you recreate the index with field length -"recipe":{
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "length":{
            "type":"token_count",
            "analyzer":"standard"
          }
        }
      } Purpose of           "length":{
            "type":"token_count",
            "analyzer":"standard"
          }
is to automatically calculate number of words in receipe which is used to run terms_set query

Comment: Yes I created this new index with your code. This query works find :
`GET /index12/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "recipe.length": 3 
    }
  }
}`

Comment: @Hehop I have updated the query. Can you try it. Are all the documents having field recipe in this format  "recipe":"<word> <word>"